# Google DataFlow - Autocomplete example reading from BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I started learning Dataflow I am using this code example Autocomplete. I am trying to read from BigQuery, but I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:root:Error while visiting split
...
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 181, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer [while running 'split']
```

Code:

```
def run(argv=None):

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--output',
                  required=True,
                  help='Output file to write results to.')
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

(p  # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
 | 'read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(input_table))
 | 'split' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\']+', x))
 | 'TopPerPrefix' >> TopPerPrefix(5)
 | 'format' >> beam.Map(
   lambda (prefix, candidates): '%s: %s' % (prefix, candidates))
 | 'write' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.TextFileSink(known_args.output)))
p.run()
```

I appreciate any feedback.
Tks
Tom

Answer (score 1):

The BigQuerySource by default returns structured records, a map from columns to values from the input table.  This means that you can't directly run a re.findall over the records.

Instead, extract the particular field you care about, i.e.,

```
 | 'split' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\']+', x['my_string_field']))
```